# who to write multilanguage or only( urdu) in wpf application textbox with vb.net?

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

This code is not working. What is done by this code? plz help me!

```
Public Sub urdu_GotFocus(ByVal InputLang As InputLanguage)
   If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLang) = -1 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   End If
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLang
End Sub
```

if i try this code

```
Private Sub urdu_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs, ByVal InputLang As InputLanguage) Handles urdu.TextChanged
    If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLang) = 1 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    End If
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLang
End Sub
```

then this error occurred 
Error   1   Method 'Private Sub urdu_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs, InputLang As System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage)' cannot handle event 'Public Event TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature.    C:\Users\atk\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\insert.xaml.vb   146 126 WpfApplication1
 what i am doing wrong please guide me?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have an error message? Exception?

Comment: nothing dear gabor no exception but not working also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1502148/g%c3%a1bor-bakos

Comment: Hi Sonia, I am not familiar with the special language support (and I have no requirements to support urdu text either), but the not working question still stands. So no exception, no error messages. Do you see the text? Or you cannot add the urdu text to the code? It is really not clear what is you problem (at least for me).

Comment: who can i clear it ?

Comment: [ask] Edit the question and state what is not working, how did you try to call the method, what happened, what did you expect. These kind of things are essential to get a useful response.

Comment: did you ever write multilanguage like urdu arabic japanies in textbox or nt idea who to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying what it is you are trying to do,
The objective was not clear from your original post.

First of all, you should make sure that you have URDU installed in your KEYBOARDS/LANGUAGES - Note this is not the same as having an URDU font!

If you use windows the installation of a new keyboard should be similar to below step #1 to step #7

If you already have the URDU KEYBOARD installed, then jump right to the end of my solution and review the code there.

Step #1
Open CONTROL PANEL and select CLOCK/LANGUAGES/REGION
[image]

Step #2
Select REGIONAL AND LANGUAGE OPTIONS
[image]

Step #3
Click on CHANGE KEYBOARDS and OTHER INPUT METHODS
[image]

Step #4
Click On ADD button

[image]

Step #5
Select URDU language and click on OK button
[image]

Step #6
Confirm that the URDU language is listed and Click On Okay button
[image]

Step #7
Click On Okay button
[image]

Once you have added URDU to your installed languages list
Continue from here.

Using the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim counter As Integer = Nothing
  If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Count > 0 Then
    For counter = 0 To InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Count - 1
       ComboBox2.Items.Add(InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(counter).LayoutName)
    Next
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
  If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)) = (-1) Then
    Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
  Else
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(ComboBox2.SelectedIndex)
  End If
End Sub
```

You should be able to select URDU language, And then type in urdu in any textbox

[image]

[image]

#### Another Update

Hello Sonia,
I think this is what you wanted?
As per the comments in your comments below?

```
Private Sub txtEnglish_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtEnglish.GotFocus
  InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(0)
End Sub

Private Sub txtUrdu_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUrdu.GotFocus
  InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(1)
End Sub
```

Maybe this link maybe of help to you Sonia?
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38751/Building-Multilingual-WPF-Applications

Comment: dear zaf khan sory for late reply this is not solving my problem i just need to right urdu into textbox but its not happening?

Comment: thanks a lot dear its helps me lot but still little confusion here which i cant elaborate first sorry but actually i have no idea who to explain question i have already installed churlp urdu phontec keyboard in os with that tool i can write any where urdu but i want that i dont want to select urdu or english from churlp or as above defined i have simple two text box one for name in english second for urdu automatically in english text box enter english and in urdu text box only urdu

Comment: Private Sub txt1_GotKeyboardFocus(sender As Object, e As KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs) Handles txt1.GotKeyboardFocus
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(1)
    End Sub
    Private Sub txt2_GotKeyboardFocus(sender As Object, e As KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs) Handles txt2.GotKeyboardFocus
        InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages(0)
    End Sub
شکریہ بھائی میرا کام ہو گیا بڑی مہربانی آپ کی اللہ آپ کو اس کی جزا دے

Answer (score 0):

when you installed Arabic/Urdu or any other language .
if you want to install input language sea above post.

then make simple code of one line.

it will type the desire language as you selected from Task bar.

```
 Private Sub txtUrdu_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUrdu.GotFocus
    **InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage**

End Sub
```